# Getting error while running apt-get update command in Ubuntu 18.04.3 with SUDO user privileges

Tags: ubuntu-18.04

I am new to using Ubuntu. I am using putty to connect and run commands.
I am having SUDO user privileges and OS details is as per below:

NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04.3 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"

I am trying to install build-essential but getting below error:

**Command: sudo apt install build-essential**

```
Reading package lists... Done <br />
Building dependency tree <br />
Reading state information... Done <br />
Package build-essential is not available, but is referred to by another package. <br />
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source <br />

E: Package 'build-essential' has no installation candidate
```

I have run the same thing without sudo keyword

**Command: apt install build-essential**,  but getting below error

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied) <br />
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root? <br />
```

After this I have tried updating apt-get using below command:

**Command: sudo apt-get update**

Result:

```
Err:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease 401  Authorization Required [IP: 10.15.0.115 8080] <br />
Err:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
  401  Authorization Required [IP: 10.15.0.115 8080] <br />
Err:3 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
  401  Authorization Required [IP: 10.15.0.115 8080] <br />
Err:4 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  401  Authorization Required [IP: 10.15.0.113 8080] <br />
```

Above error is just a snapshot (due to number of links exceeds the limit)

**I am getting above Authorisation issues. Can somebody please let me know why I am getting this authorization issues and how I can resolve these issues?**

Comment: You are working behind a proxy, that's why.

Answer (score 0):

Please try over a different network. Sometimes due to proxy restriction like in-office network, we don't have rights to download from such sites.